# How to get consumer offset value of kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have `producer` which is sending messages to a topic continuously.

Suppose my `consumer` consumed 1 to 10 messages, before consuming the 11th message it was crashed , when it get back `producer` produced 100 messages let say now messages are  110, I know that When a `consumer` joins a `consumer group` it will fetch the last committed offset so it will restart to read from 11 but I want to print these offset values in log using `java` and making sure that it wont miss a message

Also how can we get the topic wise TTL in `kafka`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ConsumerRecord you can get all the metadata corresponding to a topic

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topicNameList , new HandleRebalance())
            String kafkaMessages = null
            try{
                while(true){
                   ConsumerRecords kafkaRecords
                   kafkaRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(100)
                     for(ConsumerRecord record: kafkaRecords){
                       partition = record.partition()
                       offset = record.offset()
                       topicName = record.topic()
                         Object message = record.value()
                       }
```